# "publish_action" permission in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have created a demo for facebook integration using the latest `Facebook SDK(4.6.0)`.

Before 2 days ago and my application was running successfully.

But, as of now my application could not share the status on Facebook and could not getting `publish_action` permission. 
I did not made any change in code.

Is anyone know why this happening ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080255/facebook-publish-action-permission-not-working-for-posting have a look over here

Comment: @Jaimin Modi : From which Facebook account you are trying ? Is it development or something else ?

Comment: @AndiGeeky my own facebook account.

Comment: @Jaimin Modi : Is it the same account as in which your application is registered..?

Comment: @AndiGeeky yes it is the same account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Facebook has released new api 2.5.**

So you need to first update your api from your Deverloper facebook account.

Follow below steps :

> 1) Login with your facebook a/c
>
> 2) Check your app's API Version either it is 2.4 or 2.5..
>
> 3) If it is 2.4 then your app should be worked but if it's changed
>   then you need to give permission from your account to share the status
>   on facebook.
>
> 4) Go to Tool & support where select Graph and api.
>
> 5) And give publish_action permission over there.

For detailed explanation please refer below link :

[iOS :How to get Facebook Album Photo's Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234)

The above link is for album permission but you can set your required permission.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: _“Facebook Api is upgraded from 2.4 to 2.5.”_ – that’s a statement that is not entirely true … Facebook has _released_ v2.5 recently; but that doesn’t mean that existing apps need to upgrade immediately.

Comment: @CBroe : sorry my mistake for interpreting wrods wrongly.

Comment: No prob, just wanted to clarify that, so that people reading this don’t get the wrong idea and think they have to upgrade their apps immediately.

Answer (score 2):

did you change account or try to post in others account. As to post to wall apart from the developers account you need the app to be approved by facebook Please refer the following links.
1) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#review
2) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0.